# TFS plugin for EclipseCDT error with paths

Tags: plugins, tfs, eclipse-cdt, azure-devops

I am using Eclipse CDT (4.2 Juno) on both Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.02. I have sucessfully installed Eclipse Plugin for TFS. And it works well on Windows 7 machine. I created repository on codeplex. Now I installed TFS plugin on Ubuntu Eclipse CDT. Everything went OK. But when I tried to import projects from repository, problem arise.

What I see as a problem is that TFS plugin on Ubuntu Eclipse CDT pick up mapping (local directory) from  Windows 7 machine, and then it tries to place (import) files under that directory. Path which it tries to create (and what is causing java null pointer exception) looks like this:

`Importing $/cplusplus/ArrayDemo` (this is server path and this is OK) `to /home/nenad/C:/Nenad/workspaceplus/cplusplus/ArrayDemo` (this is local path and this is totally wrong)

That is completely malformed path. I need to import that (and all of the others) projects under `/home/nenad/workspace/cpp4d5ed` on my linux machine.

[image]

[image]

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting the Workspace and make new mapping.

Comment: Finally I resolved it with double clicking on (I wasn't aware I can do it) windows path and substituted it with linux path (/home/nenad/workspace/cpp4d5ed) I did it for each project. and now it's OK. I will see what will happen with new projects.